# plot with euler function and can't change the marginn

Tags: r, plot, margin

I used the euler package to draw venn diagram and why I can't change the margin?

```
tiff("Desktop/aa.tiff", units="in", width=4, height=4, res=500)
par(mar = c(5, 50, 5, 5))
A= c("1","2","3","4")
B= c("1","5","3","4")
plot(
  euler(list(a = A,
             b =B)),
  fills = list(fill = c("red", "deepskyblue3"), alpha = 0.4), quantities = TRUE)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 0):

Problems solved by author euler
https://github.com/jolars/eulerr/issues/49#event-2299412142